# Application Starting with error and not showing migration status

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, distillery, edeliver

#### Environment

- Phoenix version: 1.3.4
- Ecto version: 2.1
- Edeliver version: edeliver v1.4.5
- Elixir version: 1.6.3
- Build tool and version (distillery): distillery v2.0.10
- Operating system (on build / deploy hosts): Ubuntu 16.04.4 x64
- Are you using an umbrella project (yes|no): yes

#### Current behavior

I'm deploying an umbrella project with the following structure:

```
- apps/
-- app_web <--- Phoenix app
-- app <--- Ecto app
```

When I run `mix edeliver start production` I get an error but the application starts successfully:

```
-----> starting production servers

production node:

  user    : user
  host    : server-1
  path    : /home/user/apps/app/app_release
  response: ▸  Received 'pang' from app@127.0.0.1!
▸  Possible reasons for this include:
▸    - The cookie is mismatched between us and the target node
▸    - We cannot establish a remote connection to the node
▸  Received 'pang' from app@127.0.0.1!
▸  Possible reasons for this include:
▸    - The cookie is mismatched between us and the target node
▸    - We cannot establish a remote connection to the node
▸  Given the following expression: Elixir.Edeliver.run_command([:monitor_startup_progress, "app", :compact])
▸  The remote call failed with:
▸  ** (exit) :undef
▸      Edeliver.run_command([:monitor_startup_progress, "app", :compact])
▸      (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
▸      (elixir) src/elixir.erl:265: :elixir.eval_forms/4
▸      (elixir) lib/code.ex:590: Code.eval_quoted/3
▸      (kernel) rpc.erl:197: anonymous fn/5 in :rpc.handle_call_call/6


START DONE!
```

Also, I get the following error when trying to get the migrations status on production: `mix edeliver show migrations on production`:

```
-----> migrations in production servers

production node:

  user    : app
  host    : server-1
  path    : /home/user/apps/app/app_release
  response: ▸  Given the following expression: Elixir.Edeliver.run_command([:list_pending_migrations, "app", ""])
▸  The remote call failed with:
▸  ** (exit) :undef
▸      Edeliver.run_command([:list_pending_migrations, "app", ""])
▸      (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
▸      (elixir) src/elixir.erl:265: :elixir.eval_forms/4
▸      (elixir) lib/code.ex:590: Code.eval_quoted/3
▸      (kernel) rpc.erl:197: anonymous fn/5 in :rpc.handle_call_call/6
```

#### Expected behavior

I expect the application to not start when an error occurs and to show the migration status when calling the command.

Comment: Have you looked into both nodes (connect with the elixir shell) and see if they have the same cookie? The error suggests that the 2 services are started with different cookies - see https://railsware.com/blog/2014/03/26/interconnecting-elixir-nodes/

Comment: How did you configure your releases in `rel/config.exs`? This error upon deployment might be a symptom of an elixir deployment that does not include your app(s). You might have to do something like `set applications: [:other_app]` in the release config.